# Override WebView's `onAudioFocusChanged` behaviour

Tags: android, android-webview, android-audiomanager

I would like to know if is there any way a `WebView` [onAudioFocusChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener) can be overridden.

The reason I want to do that is because I am developing an app where a video plays in the WebView and I want certain things to happen when it receives an `onAudioFocusChange` callback.

If is there a possibility to make the `WebView` not to fire a `requestAudioFocus` event, I would also be happy :)

I googled it and searched on StackOverflow, but not luck on finding the answer.

Comment: please explain why you want to override and what is the case ?